# Клик - удаления токена - выход юзера

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как удалить токен по клику на кнопку - она будет в хедер(Выйти)

Мой пример создание токена

```
actions: {
    retriewToken(context, credentials) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //получаем токен по email/pass
            axios.post('mobile/login', {
                phone: credentials.phone,
                code: credentials.code
            })
                .then(response => {
                    const token = response.data.result.token //беру токен - ключ
                    localStorage.setItem('retriewToken', token)
                    context.commit('retriewToken', token)
                    resolve(response)
                    console.log('Data ', response)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    if (e.response.status === 401) {
                        alert('Невірний логін чи пароль', e)
                    }
                });
        })
    },
},
```

мутация

```
mutations: {
    retriewToken(state, token) { // мутация токена
        state.token = token
        state.isAuth = true
    } }
```

State

```
state: {
    token: token || null }
```

const

```
state: {
    isAuth: !!token,
    token: token || null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/actions.html), например `LOGOUT`, повесить его на `@click` кнопки выход:

Ваш стор:

```js
mutations: {
  retriewToken(state, token) {
    state.token = token;
    state.isAuth = Boolean(token); // приводим значение токена к boolean
  },
},
actions: {
  LOGOUT({ commit }) {
    // какие либо необходимые вам дополнительные действия
    commit('retriewToken', null);
  },
},
```

Ваш компонент:

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['LOGOUT']),
},
```

Ваш темплейт:

```html
<button @click="LOGOUT">
  Выход
</button>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@pavelgonzales/best-practices-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-vue-8b769589001a